# How can i align the text in placeholder in daypicker moment react?

Tags: reactjs

i am following the example here [enter link description here](https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input)

however, the result output of text is align left rather than center align,

i wanna as how to make the text in placeholder align center?

here is my code:

```
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
    import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';
```

here

```
return (
     <div>
                  帐单开始日期:
                    <DayPickerInput 
                      placeholder = {"test"}
                      onDayChange={startDate => this.handleStartDate(startDate)} 
                    />
                  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder

Comment: can you give more hints ?thanks